# Defining previous post time php

Tags: php, rss

I have a listing of calendar events. Right now, it only posts the day if it is different than the previous day. So all the Sunday events list under one "Sunday" heading, etc. I am trying to set up the time heading to act the same way. i.e., only list the time once, and all the corresponding events underneath that heading. How do I define the previous time, so that I can echo the time only if it's a new time?

```
<?php
            $started_loop = false;
            $previousDay = 0;
            $sameDay = false;
            foreach($this->occurrences->channel->item as $occurrence) {

                // Extract time stamp from description
                $day = $this->getTimeStampFromDescription($occurrence->description);
                $imageURL = $this->getIMGURLFromDescription($occurrence->description);

                $dayDate = date('d', $day);
                $sameDay = ( ($dayDate == $previousDay) ? true : false);    // Set whether or not the post is the same day as the last one                              

                if($n > $max_events)
                    break;              // Stop loop if we've reached the maximum number of allowable events

                ?>

                <!-- Second eventful day of the week (Identical) -->
                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="span9">
                    <h3 class="event_week_day"><?php if (!$sameDay) echo date('l, M j',$day); ?></h3>

                        <!-- First event for the day -->
                        <a href="<?php echo $occurrence->link ?>">
                            <p class="event_week_single">
                                <b><?php echo(date('g:i A ',$day) )?></b><br><?php echo ($occurrence->title); ?>
                            </p>
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Same as day. Get current time, compare to previous time, if not the same, set previous to current, and display. Be sure to reset previous time when previous day changes.

Comment: Thanks! How do I reset the time when the day changes?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
$previousDay = 0;
$sameDay = false;

...

$dayDate = date('d', $day);
$sameDay = ( ($dayDate == $previousDay) ? true : false);

...

<?php echo(date('g:i A ',$day) )?>
```

With:

```
$previousDay = 0;
$previousHour = 0;
$sameDay = false;
$sameHour = false;

...

$dayDate = date('d', $day);
$dayHour = date('g:i A', $day);
if ( $dayDate == $previousDay ) {
    $sameDay = true;
else {
    $sameDay = false;
    $previousHour = 0;
    $previousDay = $dayDate;
}
if ( $dayHour == $previousHour ) {
    $sameHour = true;
else {
    $sameHour = false;
    $previousHour = $dayHour;
}

...

<?php if (!$sameHour) { echo date('g:i A ',$day); } ?>
```